# Styling side by side elements

Tags: html, css

I have figured out how to set two HTML elements side by side. I want to have a text paragraph on the left and an image on the right.
Currently, my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>
<body>

 <div style="width: 50%; height: 100px; float: left;" >
    <h2> What We Do</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis.</p>
    </div>

<div style="margin-left:50%; "><img style=" max-width: 100%; height: auto;" src="https://images.designtrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/06094112/Beautiful-Mountain-HD-Backgrounds.jpg" >
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is results in an two column layout, but I want to know how to format.

I want to add padding to the text, but when I do so, the image is messed up completely. How can I padding padding to my text so that there is space around it? I tried to add `padding:20px;` to the `<div>` that has the text which doesn't work.

```
<div style="width: 50%; height: 100px; float: left; padding:20px;">
    <h2> What We Do</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use rather `display: flex` or `grid`. `float` should be only used if you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Avoid the use if inline `style` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use Grid with a media query for smaller screens:

```css
article {
  display: grid;
}

div {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  article {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>
    <h2> What We Do</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem.
      Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://images.designtrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/06094112/Beautiful-Mountain-HD-Backgrounds.jpg">
</article>
```

Comment: Why are you using `grid` for 1-dimentional item?

Comment: @RoboRobok I find it simple to work with, you can add a solution with another layout tool like Flexbox if you want

Comment: Flexbox with `flex-grow: 1` on all items will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

use box-sizing:border-box, after applying padding, so the padding will be calculated within the width

For more info [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

```html
<div style="width: 50%; height: 100px; float: left; padding:20px;box-sizing:border-box" >
    <h2> What We Do</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis.</p>
    </div>

<div style="margin-left:50%; "><img style=" max-width: 100%; height: auto;" src="https://images.designtrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/06094112/Beautiful-Mountain-HD-Backgrounds.jpg" >
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) makes it really simple to control the layout.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: max-content;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

.info {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-item info">
    <h2> What We Do</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem.
      Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-item">
    <div><img class="image" src="https://images.designtrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/06094112/Beautiful-Mountain-HD-Backgrounds.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to wrap both `<div>` inside a flex-box. And adding `border-box` as value for `box-sizing` property. You can read more about `box-sizing` here: [Box Sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp) and about [Flex Box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) here. Both are pretty useful to placing items side by side.

Here is a sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%;">
        <div style="width: 50%; height: 100px; padding:20px;">
            <h2> What We Do</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore
                magna aliqua. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Est velit
                egestas
                dui id ornare arcu odio ut sem. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum
                facilisis.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 50%; padding: 20px;">
            <img style=" max-width: 100%; height: auto;"
                src="https://images.designtrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/06094112/Beautiful-Mountain-HD-Backgrounds.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The `box-sizing` will prevent your image from changing position when adding padding to the div. And `flex-box` is much better way to position things instead of `float` as it offers more functionality and can also position things vertically.

Here is another great article related to [Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) - Must Read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example for side by side

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
    flex: 1;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}  

.flex-child:first-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-child magenta">
    Flex Column 1
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-child green">
    Flex Column 2
  </div>
  
</div>
```